# How to inject data to a NestJS Interceptor

Tags: typescript, nestjs, interceptor

I have worked in NestJS with an interceptor, where I can add data to the response header, but all the examples I have seen, and what I have used, is inserting static data.

To work with some dynamic data, I have used a hard coded call to get data, such as my service name and version, but I want to be able to pass data to add into the response.

For instance, when making calls to the services, there might be a need to add a HTTP header to the response, and the service call to the back end server, gets this data.  Ideally, I want to be able to pass this data into the interceptor, as I would like the standard response handling to continue.

My current interceptor goes to the class to read the data from package.json.

```
@Injectable()
export class AddServiceVersionInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<unknown> {
        const AppInfo:AppService = new AppService();
        const ServiceInfo:string = `${AppInfo.GetName()}/${AppInfo.GetVersion()}`;

        const ResponseObj:ExpressResponse = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
        ResponseObj.setHeader('my-service', ServiceInfo );

        return next.handle().pipe();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to dependency inject additional information, such as a list of headers that need to be added into response.  I do not know how to pass data to the inceptor in NestJS.

As a global interceptor, I want to be able to supply the data, as opposed to having the interceptor call a service that makes a call to the back end, which would be a second call to the back end.

I was thinking the constructor() might be the way to do it, but as this is populated and created by NestJS, I am not sure if that would work as the data is different per route, and is returned from the back end service calls.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @GilGrossman not directly.  I have to make calls in the interceptor to get data, similar to what I did with AppService().